# Youtube API custom playlists show videos names

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I've been trying to do this for a few weeks.
I tried many solutions here but none seems to work anymore.

I have this code to load the playlist:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  console.log(id_playlist);
  event.target.cuePlaylist({
    'listType': 'playlist',
    'list': id_playlist,
  });

}
```

How i can display the name of all the playlist videos in a separate div ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the api here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

You'll need to paginate through the all the pages (each page can only have 50 videos max) and grab the video names